# Receive email to eml file

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I want users to have a dummy address to send e-mails to.

```
    user-1@myapp.com
    user-2@myapp.com
    user-230498@myapp.com
    ...
```

How can I make sure my App will get the full e-mail in an eml file (if possible with user-id).

So my app will get an file like user-230498-RANDOM_STRING.eml? (my app will be able to parse the eml file and process it (and deletes it after process)).

Comment: you will need to pipe the email to php to parse it. heres a quick tutorial http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/

Comment: But are there any (easy) ways to do this on an EC2 (LAMP) instance? Without using something like cPanel?